# Google Analytics Goal Completion Scope

Tags: google, google-analytics

Struggling to find the answer to this query, but is a google analytics goal conversion (URL destination) scope set at hit, session or user?

i.e. if it was at user scope and a user hit that same URL say 5 times, would the goal conversion be 5 for the user or 1?

Comment: I am surprised that I wasn't able to find this in the GA documentation, but a goal can be converted once per session. If I can find an official reference I'll submit an actual answer here.

Comment: Thanks @Reve I struggled to find it in the online documentation too, hence reaching out on here.